# How to get rid of overlapping node shapes when using dot2tex?

Tags: dot2tex

I'm trying to introduce multiline `dot2tex` nodes using `\parbox` like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{center}
\begin{dot2tex}
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  os [texlbl="\parbox{3cm}{\centering Operating system}"];
  exe [texlbl="\parbox{3cm}{\centering Machine code in an .exe-file}"];
  os -> exe;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me overlapping nodes:

[image: Overlapping nodes]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: not an answer but you may find it interesting that there is a new library in PGF3/TikZ to specify graphs in a similar way and get the layout done for you by lualatex...

Answer (score 2):

This is that time when you almost immediately find an answer to your own question just after you post it.

Please, refer to https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dot2tex-users/Jgyd5IcrC2c/X0SKRodbII4J for the solution provided by the package author.

To sum up, now my `dot2tex` environment looks like this:

```
\begin{dot2tex}
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  os [lblstyle="text width=3cm,align=center", label="Operating system"];
  exe [lblstyle="text width=3cm,align=center", label="Machine code in an .exe-file"];
  os -> exe;
}
\end{dot2tex}
```

and the produced result looks like this:

[image: non-overlapping nodes]

It's an issue I've been struggling with for some time, so I'll leave it here.